How do you plot unique data sets contained in one csv?
I have a large data set (consisting of many sub data sets internally of no patterned order) that resembles the following, saved as a csv:



Data Set (string)
Time(float)
Value (float)




data_name1
1.0
4.0


data_name2
1.5
5.7


data_name1
3.1
2.1


data_name3
7
8



The length of the data set is many 1000’s and contains roughly ten individual sets [data_name(1-10)].
I need to create plots of particular groupings of the individual data sets. For example, I’m after the following plots:

And similarly for other groups (data_name2, data_name5) and etc.
So far I have the following code (that does NOT work as intended - below). The code, as is, plots the whole csv without filtering on the data sets (aka it will give one line and not different lines). What way would you all recommend I accomplish this goal?
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import in data
with open('HR_data.csv', 'rt') as f:
    next(f)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data_as_list = list(reader)

# Save data as data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_list, columns=["Data Set Name", "time", "value"])

# Plotting Call
plt.plot(df['time'], df['value']) 
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)') 
plt.ylabel('Value () ') 
plt.title('Data Plotting') 

# Show Plot
plt.show()


Hi @toolic!
There are many different data sets in the csv (data_name1, data_name2, data_name3, etc) but they appear in the csv in no particular order

Seems like a pivot_table. Can you try: df.pivot_table(index="Time(float)", columns="Data Set (string)", values="Value (float)", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0,).plot() ?

One approach is the following:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_rows_per_dataset = 1000

data_sets = ['data_name1', 'data_name2', 'data_name3', 'data_name4', 'data_name5',
             'data_name6', 'data_name7', 'data_name8', 'data_name9', 'data_name10']

data = {
    'Data Set': np.random.choice(data_sets, num_rows_per_dataset),
    'Time': np.random.uniform(0, 10, num_rows_per_dataset),
    'Value': np.random.uniform(0, 100, num_rows_per_dataset)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

agg_df = df.groupby(['Time', 'Data Set']).agg({'Value': 'mean'}).unstack()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for data_name in data_sets:
    plt.plot(agg_df.index, agg_df['Value'][data_name], label=data_name)

plt.title('Plot of all data sets')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


which gives you

